# TFS web interface: is it possible to limit the history of a git repository to a precise range of commits?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In the TFS2015 web interface (CODE hub) the user can list all the commits in a specific date range.

Is it possible to list all the commits in a specific **commits** range?

This would correspond to the WebAPI functionalities described on this page: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/commits#GetalistofcommitsBetweentwoversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.
Through the "branches" controller.

With a query similar to
http://{HOST}:8080/tfs/{COLLECTION}/_git/{REPOSITORYNAME}/branches#baseVersion=GC{COMMITID}&targetVersion=GC{COMMITID}&_a=commits